# 046 MHW Real Time Clock Failure

Tags: motherboard, cmos

I'm currently in the process of rebuilding a computer from Alienware computer pieces. The motherboard itself is 046 MHW, and on boot it gives 5 beeps without any actual booting. This indicates a Real Time Clock failure. I have tried replacing the battery AND resetting with jumpers... nothing. Google doesn't seem to be able to suggest anything additional, either.

Backstory: Computer was disassembled and brought overseas in a suitcase and is currently attempted to be reassembled.

Comment: The clock circuitry might actually be damaged. In that case you're probably out of luck.

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: You can try this guide to see if any of these trouble shooting steps help you. http://www.pcguide.com/ts/x/comp/mbsys/gen_Failure.htm . I'm inclined to think that the boards is a write off though.

Comment: I saw that guide earlier on but it didn't help me any further.